# Regex for 8,2 decimal with thousand separator in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have tried a few regex's of my own but have always had some bug or the other.

My requirement is to get a regex for 8,2 decimal, e.g. 000,000.00

- 6 digits integer part
- 2 digits in decimal part

Invalid ones are as follows

- 2,2
- 2,2.2.2
- 12,12
- 1,1,1,1

Valid ones are as follows

- 12
- 1,000.00
- 220,000.00
- 173747

**Update**:
This to check a valid input from user.
Fraction part or commas are not mandatory.

Comment: You shall use DecimalFormat for formatting numbers

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks for formatting.

Comment: see the answer..is this ok?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the replies, will check them and get back asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For at most 8 digits before decimal**

I came up with a rather complicated regular expression (assuming the numbers have mandatory `,`)

```
^\d{1,3}((?:(?<=\d),(?=\d{3})\d{3})){0,2}(\.\d{2})?$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tI1iC9/4)**

You can add an or condition in above regex for matching non-comma patterns

```
^(\d{1,3}((?:(?<=\d),(?=\d{3})\d{3})){0,2}|^\d{0,8})(\.\d{2})?$
```

*Java Regex*

```
^(\\d{1,3}((?:(?<=\\d),(?=\\d{3})\\d{3})){0,2}|\\d{0,8})(\\.\\d{2})?$
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/3DtSJi)**

**For at most 6 digits before decimal use**

```
^(\d{1,3}((?:(?<=\d),(?=\d{3})\d{3})){0,1}|^\d{0,6})(\.\d{2})?$
```

Comment: Shouldn't it capture `222,000,000,123.00` too?

Comment: @TamasHegedus till my understanding of question, there should be maximum 8 digits before decimal and 2 digits after decimal

Comment: Hmm, so thats what `8,2` means. I think you are right.

Comment: Hi @rock321987, there is a small correction, the integer part should contain only 6 digits, you have done it for 8 digits.

Comment: @user1782556 then how you are considering `22,000,000.00` valid?

Comment: @user1782556 use this regex `^(\d{1,3}((?:(?<=\d),(?=\d{3})\d+)){0,1}|^\d{0,8})`

Comment: @rock321987, above answer, which was provided yesterday seems to be working just fine except for the integer length part

Comment: @rock321987, It still seems to be accepting 8 digits in integer part

Comment: @rock321987, I believe you need to replace "8" with "6"

Comment: @user1782556 that was simple one..i missed it..if its ok you can accept the answer then

Comment: @rock321987, seems you missed to update to "6" at other above regex's in your answer.

Comment: @user1782556 see the most last regex `^(\d{1,3}((?:(?<=\d),(?=\d{3})\d{3})){0,1}|^\d{0,6})(\.\d{2})?$`..i have updated it..i had missed it earlier

Comment: @rock321987, Its better you update "8" to "6" everywhere, else you can just have the last(latest) regex and remove others.

Comment: @user1782556 I am not removing it because your question says `Regex for 8,2 decimal` which typically can be interpreted as 8 digits before decimal and 2 digits after decimal..though, I have added notes  in my answer

Comment: @rock321987, The number "the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2" according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190476.aspx

Comment: @user1782556 what do you want exactly? I was just telling that it depends on how one interprets the question..I maybe wrong..I had also added notes in bold

Comment: @rock321987, I am just concerned, my question can be misleading.

Comment: @user1782556 don't worry..people will get it

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/^(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.(?:[0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{1,3})?|[1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*)?)$/
```

[See in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fU6bX6/1)